# How to enable FULLTEXT Search index in xampp server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, full-text-search

When I'm trying to use full-text search index with PHP

```
SELECT * FROM nlist WHERE MATCH(gcomp,jtype) AGAINST ('$nforg' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

it's seems an error.

> General error: 1214 The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Answer (score 0):

What type of table are you using, and did you mark the columns as a fulltext index?

Comment: Yes, I want to make some particular column.

Comment: As I askded before: what type of table is it?
Also I think you should tag your qeustion as MySql because your qeustion is not about php, but instead about mysql.

Comment: It's about php and mysql